# If the article title ends in closing punctuation, do we still add a period in an APA reference?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, italics, style-manuals

I have a question about citing a reference in APA format.  The following reference was created by one of the members of my school group for a paper we are working on (let's just dismiss indentation on SE); I do not yet know if it was created manually or generated:

> The Standard Group. (2012, September 12). *Is Ghana the next African economic tiger?.* Retrieved July 19, 2014, from http://www.standardmedia.co.ke/?articleID=2000065384

The title of the article `"Is Ghana the next African economic tiger?"` ends in a question mark.  As shown in the reference, there is a period appended, `"Is Ghana the next African economic tiger?."` Two questions:

- Does the period still get appended to the end?
- Is the period supposed to be italicized?

Comment: Did you mean to repeat the title? I can't tell which of the two post-title periods you're asking about in the second question…

Comment: Why not cite it in the format that The Standard Group demand in their terms of service?

Comment: Isn't this essentially a question requesting one particular opinion about style rather than a genuine request for an overview of accepted different usages?  Which I believe could well be claimed to make it OT because of subjectiveness.

Comment: @Frank - paper requires APA format, no other, unless The Standard Group is APA format.  I am unfamiliar with multiple format styles and am asking only about this one specific style.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - fixed duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I'm asking about a specific style, not any others; therefore there is no subjectiveness, but a single, specific answer.

Comment: @JoshDM That’s not what he meant. The Standard Group [T&C](http://www.standardmedia.co.ke/?contentPage=terms-of-service) require that you name the SG as the source, rather than the author of the article. You should also use the permalink for the article, not a link to their mobile site.

Comment: @Janus - fixing the link momentarily.

Comment: Yowsa; didn't realize we had to check every website's own TOS to determine citation format.  Sucks for the author.

Comment: Sucks indeed, but most fall into one of the more common citation format (if only they'd just add a 'cite this' link at the bottom of each page). To answer your question about the 'extra period' see here - (second green chunk down) http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/07/punctuating-the-reference-list-entry.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use the American Psychological Association (APA) citation and format style (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APA_style) Wikipedia article) rather than general English usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - then vote to close the other 5 currently-open APA questions as well because you've set a precedent by leaving them open.  I confirmed their existence before asking this question.

Comment: I have followed your advice. Thank you. But your 'You have set a precedent by [not close-voting ...]' is unwarranted; I am not sole arbiter of on-topicity on the site any more than I was involved in the assassination of Caesar.

Comment: Tim Lymington says (in meta) "There seems to be a general consensus that questions (like this one) which ask about how to fit your text within MLA (or other stylebooks) are off-topic, since both 'what MLA mandates' and 'the way your professor prefers papers set out' are valuable advice to the student, but cannot be classified as 'English Language & Usage'."

Comment: Kanye West says (on Twitter), "Shoot for the stars, so if you fall you land on a cloud."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer appears to be ***no***.

On page 22 of [this sample reference list](http://flash1r.apa.org/apastyle/basics/data/resources/references-sample.pdf) by the APA, there is an example of an article that ends in a question marks, just like yours (though it’s from a paper journal, not an online one):

> Ohnishi, T., Matsuda, H., Tabira, T., Asada, T., & Uno, M. (2001). Changes in brain morphology in Alzheimer’s disease and exaggerated aging process? *American Journal of Neuroradiology, 22,* 1680–1685.

As you can see, they leave out the period after the title when it ends in a punctuation mark. This is similar to how any final punctuation in author name(s) is merged with the required period: “… & Uno, M. (2001)”, not “… & Uno, M.. (2001).”—though of course with author names, you’re a lot less likely to come up against question or exclamation marks.

You should also note that articles are not italicised; only full works and journals are italicised.

Comment: Please provide a citation for this source ;)

Comment: @Frank Shush, you!

Comment: The citation generators that are built into some interfaces for databases of periodical/scholarly literature often add the period where it is superfluous, as here, which shows how underdeveloped the algorithms are. I always advise students to use such auto-generated citations as starting points but to take responsibility for correcting them. Article titles in APA references are not "italicised," as JBJ notes; I would add that (contrary to OP's example) they are not enclosed within quotation marks either.

Comment: @Brian He only adds the quotation marks when discussing them in the question (where perhaps he doesn't use APA); in the actual example reference, there are no quotation marks. (Incidentally, were yours around the word ‘italicised’ scare quotes? And if so, why?)

Comment: They are not scare quotes, inasmuch as I am precisely quoting a specific and identified source, who spells the word otherwise than as I (an American) would and do. For me to Americanize your spelling were to misrepresent you; not to do so were to misrepresent myself; the quotation marks seemed thus the least of three evils.

Comment: @Brian I had, for some reason, mentally placed you as a Brit! Though no quotes and an Americani(s/z)ed spelling would just have made them your own words, equally true for all that. :-)